# what are the local-service="true" remote-service="false" in service.xml

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Can anyone please elaborate what are the `local-service="true" remote-service="false"` parameters in service.xml.

Comment: @Pankaj Kathiriya i am not able to see your last answer!

Comment: This is a very well-documented feature of Liferay's Service builder. What kind of elaboration would you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local-service="true"`
This will create classes to access your services within the same JVM.

`remote-service="true"`
This will create classes to access your services from outside.

In your case (local=true;remote=false) - you will be able to call the services in your portlet (or the whole portal, depends on how you set them up), but won't be able to call them from  outside (for example from some SOAP client or a mobile application, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Below is brief detail from `liferay-service-builder_6_1_0.dtd`.

If the local-service value is true, then the service will generate the local
interfaces for the service. The default value is false.

If the remote-service value is true, then the service will generate remote
interfaces for the service. The default value is true.

You can also refer to [link](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/write-remote-service-classes-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en)